# Protected fields and generics

Tags: java, generics, comparator, protected

I have an abstract class `MotorFahrzeug` and an extending class `LKW` as shown below. I wrote a generic class with type parameter `<T extends MotorFahrzeug>` implementing a comparator. I'm wondering why the method `compare( T m1, T m2 )` in this generic class has access to the protected fields. Can someone explain this, please?

```
package de.bauer;

public abstract class MotorFahrzeug {

    protected int id;
    protected int hubraum;
    protected int leistung;


    // some stuff
    }
}


package de.bauer;

public class LKW extends MotorFahrzeug {

    private String kategorie = "Nutzfahrzeug";

    // Konstruktor
    LKW(int i, int l, int h) {

      // some stuff   
    }

    // some stuff

}

package de.bauer;

import java.util.Comparator;

public class VergleichHubraum<T extends MotorFahrzeug> implements Comparator<T> {

    @Override
    public int compare(T m1, T m2) {

        int retValue = -1;

        if( m1.hubraum == m2.hubraum)
            retValue = 0;

        if( m1.hubraum > m2.hubraum)
            retValue = 1;


        return retValue;
    }
}
```

Comment: `de.bauer` `de.bauer` `de.bauer`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a declaration like

```
package de.bauer;
public class VergleichHubraum<T extends MotorFahrzeug> implements Comparator<T> {
```

The type `T` is guaranteed to be bound to a subtype of `MotorFahrzeug`. Since `MotorFahrzeug` is in the same package as the class declared above, you can access any of its `protected` members through a reference of type `T`.